# Agregar usuarios a un proyecto Git

Tags: git

tengo el siguiente problema.. en un servidor tengo un proyecto y esta en un repositorio de Bitbucket.

Si hago `git shortlog -sn`

Me lista:

```
36  root
 4  Mi User
```

Necesito agregar otro usuario autorizado desde Bitbucker para que hagas commits y push

Comment: Si no me equivoco, podés agregar personas al grupo desde la webapp.

Comment: La persona si esta agregada como usuario en bitbucket, pero para hacer push siempre pide mi password y no la del otro usuario, posiblemente porque le falte configurarlo y en eso necesito ayuda :(

Comment: talves debes cambiar de usuario git config name y git config email

Comment: por ese lado lo veo @x-rw, sin embargo no se como resolverlo

Comment: Si te pide siempre el user y pass entonces te conviene configurar el ssh, por lo menos a mi me sirvió así.

Comment: Solo pide el password de mi usuario, como puedo hacer que pida user y password?

Comment: Sala de chat [aca](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82472/agregar-usuarios-a-git)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debes de dirigirte a `Settings -> User and group access -> Users` y agrega el usuario por su correo. Recuerda que el usuario debe de estar registrado en bitbucket para que te aparezca en la lista.

Aqui una imagen para que te puedas guiar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien comprueba que la url del repositorio no contenga tu usuario. Ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
git remote -v
```

Si en la url aparece tu usuario entonces tienes que editar y cambiarlo por el usuario que va utilizar el repositorio. Eso se hace con el siguiente comando:

```
git remote set-url origin  https://<nombre_de_tu_cuenta>@bitbucket.org/<la_nueva_cuenta>/<nombre_repositorio>
```

Comment: Estimado, eso ya lo realicé, solo que en el servidor no esta configurado ese otro usuario, no se como hacerlo, pero solo aparece el mio.

Comment: El usuario que quieres agregar esta registrado en bitbucket?

Comment: Si, de hecho puede clonar el repositorio y modificarlo y desde su maquina local hacer push y pull, pero en el servidor solo aparece mi usuario

Comment: No aparece en los commits del servidor? A eso te refieres?

Comment: No, lo que sucede es que el otro usuario no puede hacer pull ni push en el servidor, porque siempre pide mi contraseña

Comment: Como creamos un chat? Me gustaria ayudarte.

Comment: Los dos tienen suficiente reputacion como para crear una sala dentro de las salas de [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @gbianchi Es que no se como se hace (><)

Comment: sala de chat [aca](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82472/agregar-usuarios-a-git)

Answer (score 1):

puedes cambiar de usuario

abre git bash y configura el email y el name de tu otro usuario

```
git config --global user.email "jp@gmail.com"

git config --global user.name 'JuanPerez'
```

y puedes verificar el usuario con el que estas con

```
git config --list
```

Comment: Hola, lo agregue, sin embargo aun me pide MI contraseña